# How can I animate my less from "display: block" to "display: none"?

Tags: css, less, css-animations, keyframe

I have a less file that hide and display an element like the following:

```
.cmp-accordion__panel {
      &--hidden {
      display: none;
   }

   &--expanded {
     display: block;
     -webkit-animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-out;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5%);
 }
100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
   }     
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5%);
  }
  100% {
   opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
   }
}
```

In my JavaScript, I toggle the class name of the element between "cmp-accordion__panel--hidden" and "cmp-accordion__panel--expanded" if the event is triggered. I use keyframe and opacity to animate the transition from "display:none" to "display:block".

However, when I go from "display:block" to "display:none" to hide the element, the effect happens INSTANTLY. What should I add to animate the hiding?

Comment: try adding a small delay `animation: slide-down 0.5s ease-out 0.1s;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif What does it even do? slide-down is for animation from "display:none" to "display: block". I am trying to do animation from "display:block" to "display:none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate or transition from `display: block;` to `display: none;`, so you will need to remove this if you wish to animate it.

To ensure it fades and is removed you should animate the `visibilty` and `opacity` attributes.

Alternatively if you are using jQuery you can use the `.fadeOut()` function.

[MDN - CSS Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

[jQuery - fadeOut()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Comment: Is it because "display:none" take effect too quickly before any animation takes effect?

Comment: In a way yes, you are unable to transisiton/animate `display: none;`. You could add a third class after your animation is finished to set `display: none;` on to the element.

Comment: Does the original element still occupy space after fadeOut() of JQueryhas been called? I know that even if you set visibility and opacity to 0, the space is still occupied. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No the element won't take up any space. `fadeOut()` applies an opacity animation and then sets `display: none;` once the animation has finished.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, is not possible animate or transition from `display:block;` to `display: none;` but this could be simulated in another way and is not necessary to use CSS animations, simply CSS transitions (in addition, is not necessary anymore to use vendor-prefixes to declare transitions or animations).

Please, look at [this working example](https://codepen.io/ldetomi/pen/vYOXWLX):

**HTML** (I inserted a fake content to create an element with a relative big height)

```
<div class="cmp-accordion__panel--expanded">
  b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
[class*="cmp-accordion__panel"] {
  border:solid 1px red;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out, max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}

.cmp-accordion__panel {
   &--hidden {
      max-height:0;
      opacity:0;  
   }

   &--expanded {
     opacity:1;
     max-height:1000px;
  }
}
```

Please note that, thanks to [attribute partial value selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) I added also some rules that apply to both `*--hidden` and `*--expanded` classes (I personally prefer a general class and an addition of a second one in some cases, instead of switching between two, but I did not want to change too much your approach).

The key rule is switching between two values of `max-height` property, from a 0 value to another "*enough big*" one. If you effectively know final height of the element you can simply use also `height` property, but in case of dynamic content, max-height did the trick.

Please note also the presence of `overflow:hidden;` applied to both classes, to simulate height changes.

Finally, animation effect relies only on a CSS transition applied to `opacity` and `max-height` properties, with different timings to enhance effect.